# How to get the main blog's id and db prefix from a mu plugin?

Tags: plugins, multisite

How can one get the blog ID as well as the database prefix of the main blog in a wordpress multisite installation? Is the main blog's ID always 1? Also how can the main blog's table prefix be acquired from within the mu-plugin's code?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the constant `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE`. And to get the database table prefix, use;

```
$main_blog_prefix = $wpdb->get_blog_prefix(BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Mind if I ask when `BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE!=1`?

Comment: @MikeSchinkel I'm not sure! It might be if you have multiple *networks*, or if you (somehow or other) switched the main blog with another?

Comment: Thanks. Andrew Nacin answered me on Twitter.  http://twitter.com/nacin/status/18479360935723009

Comment: Defense against link rot: One more Q: Why would I want to set BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE to a number other than 1 in /wp-config.php. Or would I ever? –You might, but only if you want to change the main site. Typically, it'll be wp_site.site_id = 1 and wp_blogs.blog_id = 1.

Answer (score 3):

This is how we do it to be 100% as we have multiple main sites in the network installation:

```
function name_ly_get_main_blog_id () {
  global $current_site;
  global $wpdb;

  return $wpdb->get_var ( $wpdb->prepare ( "SELECT `blog_id` FROM `$wpdb->blogs` WHERE `domain` = '%s' AND `path` = '%s' ORDER BY `blog_id` ASC LIMIT 1", $current_site->domain, $current_site->path ) );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the below to get the table prefix.

```
current site table prefix : $wpdb->prefix;
Main blog table prefix : $wpdb->base_prefix;
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a function to get main site id for a given network (defaults to the active network)

```
get_main_site_id();
```

If you only need db prefix, `$wpdb->get_blog_prefix(get_main_site_id())` would suffice, but otherwise you can switch whole code blocks into other blog's context seamlessly with `switch_to_blog()` and `restore_current_blog()` functions

```
switch_to_blog(get_main_site_id());
global $wpdb; // it's now in the main site's context
$prefix = $wpdb->prefix;
// ... do your stuff
restore_current_blog();
```

But be wary of recursive calls to `switch_to_blog()`, because then context becomes hard to track and debug